# Python sort in a dictionary and a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a book index and I have read in a text file of words and their pages and have created this dictionary called 'index'

```
index={'spanning tree': {16, 99}, 'vertex': {54}, 'depth first search': {55}, 'shortest path': {55}, 'connected': {28, 54}, 'neighbor': {64, 27, 77}, 'path': {72, 19}}
```

Now I want to alphabetize the keys and put the numbers in chronological order- 
Am I able to do this in the dictionary format or do I need to convert it to a list or a string?

I tried doing this...

```
ind=list(index)
ind.sort()
return ind
```

and I got a list of the keys in alphabetical order but am not sure how to approach the numbers because they are in sets...

Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: @Marcin: I don't think the OP is sorting the dictionary by value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to convert the sets to lists too if you want to apply ordering.

The [`sorted()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) gives you a sorted list from any iterable, letting you skip a step:

```
for key in sorted(index):
    print('{:<20}{}'.format(key, ', '.join(str(i) for i in sorted(index[key]))))
```

Short demo:

```
>>> sorted(index)
['connected', 'depth first search', 'neighbor', 'path', 'shortest path', 'spanning tree', 'vertex']
>>> sorted(index['connected'])
[28, 54]
>>> for key in sorted(index):
...     print('{:<20}{}'.format(key, ', '.join(str(i) for i in sorted(index[key]))))
... 
connected           28, 54
depth first search  55
neighbor            27, 64, 77
path                19, 72
shortest path       55
spanning tree       16, 99
vertex              54
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collections module in the standard library which has an `OrderedDict` type which is just a `dict` that remembers order of insertion.

If you want a dictionary in alphabetical order, where your values are ordered lists:

```
sorted_index = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(zip(index, map(sorted, index.values()))))
```

Since that is a bit of an ugly line you can expand it out as.

```
sorted_items = sorted(index.items())
sorted_items = [(k, sorted(v)) for k, v in sorted_items]
sorted_index = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_items)
```